# Google Analytics Universal Ecommerce data not being recorded

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have been trying to move my Google Analytics E commerce tracking over to universal but I am having a few problems.  The tracking itself is working fine but not the e commerce.  I have enabled ecommerce tracking in google analytics and have added the following code:

inside printerlandtest.co.uk.cara.init.js:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-30033504-40', 'auto',{'name': 'CARATracker'});  // New tracker.
ga('CARATracker.send', 'pageview');
```

and
inside caranew.js

```
ga('CARATracker.require', 'ec'); 


function CaraGetWidgetDescription(manufacturerWidget) {
    CaraConfig();
     ga('CARATracker.set', 'Widget Impression ID E-tale', String(manufacturerWidget));

}



function CaraAddToBasket(productName, sku) {

    CaraConfig();
    ga('CARATracker.send', 'event', String(productName), 'AddToBasket', String(sku));
}

function CaraBeginTransaction(orderNo, totalPrice) {

CaraConfig();
   ga('CARATracker.ecommerce:addTransaction', String(orderNo), "", CaraPriceFix(String(totalPrice)), "", "0.00", "", "", "");
}

function CaraAddTransactionItem(orderNo, sku, productName, productCategory, productPrice, quantity) {

    CaraConfig();
    ga('CARATracker.ecommerce:addItem', {
        String(orderNo),
        String(sku),
        String(productName),
        String(productCategory),
        CaraPriceFix(String(productPrice)),
        String(quantity)
    });


function CaraEndTransaction() {

    CaraConfig();
    ga('CARATracker.ecommerce:send');  
}

function CaraPriceFix(price) {

    var fixedPrice = price;

    var pLength = price.length;
    var comma = price.indexOf(",") + 1;
    var period = price.indexOf(".") + 1;

    //comma is in the price
    if (comma != 0) {
        //if the comma is not at a 2-decimal point position
        //i.e true for 1,200
        if ((pLength - comma) > 2) {
            fixedPrice = fixedPrice.replace(",", "");
        }
    }
    //period is in the price
    if (period != 0) {
        //if the period is not at a 2-decimal point position
        //i.e true for 1.200
        if ((pLength - period) > 2) {
            fixedPrice = fixedPrice.replace(".", "");
        }
    }
    return fixedPrice;
}
```

As this is inside a clents site it is asynchronous with their own Google analytics and is set up as follows:

```
<script>  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');  ga('create', 'UA-3521256-1', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 20});  ga('send', 'pageview');</script><script src="https://where-to-buy.co/scripts/cara/printerlandtest.co.uk.cara.init.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://where-to-buy.co/scripts/cara/caranew.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On the Add to basket button their is the following code:

```
<a onclick="TrackEvent('Buy Button Click','ProductList','01327701','');CaraAddToBasket('OKI C511dn','01327701');" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_cntPlaceHlderMain_lstCategoryProducts_ctrl0_lnkBuy" class="button product_buy selected" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$cntPlaceHlderMain$lstCategoryProducts$ctrl0$lnkBuy", "", true, "", "", false, true))'><span>Added</span> </a>
```

However I am getting the following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: CaraAddToBasket is not defined**

and when I click on the Pay I get the following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: CaraBeginTransaction is not defined**

I thought I was defining them in the functions but have I got something wrong?

Is there anything else which stop the ecommerce tracking?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code and came to this solution. Removing all the new String() functions and moving the price fix function out of the array to a var above it.

Also there was a } missing behind a addtobasket function causing the JS to fail.

Now the function is running fine.

```js
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
  i[r] = i[r] || function() {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
  a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-30033504-40', 'auto', {
  'name': 'CARATracker'
}); // New tracker.
ga('CARATracker.send', 'pageview');

ga('CARATracker.require', 'ec');


function CaraGetWidgetDescription(manufacturerWidget) {
  CaraConfig();
  ga('CARATracker.set', 'Widget Impression ID E-tale', String(manufacturerWidget));

}



function CaraAddToBasket(productName, sku) {

  CaraConfig();
  ga('CARATracker.send', 'event', String(productName), 'AddToBasket', String(sku));
  alert('Debugging: added');
}

function CaraBeginTransaction(orderNo, totalPrice) {

  CaraConfig();
  ga('CARATracker.ecommerce:addTransaction', String(orderNo), "", CaraPriceFix(String(totalPrice)), "", "0.00", "", "", "");
}

function CaraAddTransactionItem(orderNo, sku, productName, productCategory, productPrice, quantity) {

  CaraConfig();
  var price = CaraPriceFix(productPrice);
  alert(price);
  ga('CARATracker.ecommerce:addItem', {
    orderNo,
    sku,
    productName,
    productCategory,
    price,
    quantity
  });
}


function CaraEndTransaction() {

  CaraConfig();
  ga('CARATracker.ecommerce:send');
}

function CaraPriceFix(price) {

  var fixedPrice = price;

  var pLength = price.length;
  var comma = price.indexOf(",") + 1;
  var period = price.indexOf(".") + 1;

  //comma is in the price
  if (comma != 0) {
    //if the comma is not at a 2-decimal point position
    //i.e true for 1,200
    if ((pLength - comma) > 2) {
      fixedPrice = fixedPrice.replace(",", "");
    }
  }
  //period is in the price
  if (period != 0) {
    //if the period is not at a 2-decimal point position
    //i.e true for 1.200
    if ((pLength - period) > 2) {
      fixedPrice = fixedPrice.replace(".", "");
    }
  }
  return fixedPrice;
}

function CaraConfig() {
  //empty
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <a onclick="CaraAddToBasket('OKI C511dn','01327701');" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_cntPlaceHlderMain_lstCategoryProducts_ctrl0_lnkBuy" class="button product_buy selected" href='#'><span>Added</span> </a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I just noticed the extra } aswel good old console it looks like it should work now ust have to wait for the data to come through on analytics (fingers crossed) thanks for your time. I actually removed the CaraConfig(); aswel as I think its obsolete.

Comment: hi Thomas unfortunately I still am not getting e commerce data through even though the alerts that are set in the code are being hit.  Do you have any other suggestions? In Behaviour overview I can see that the orderreceipt.aspx page is being hit but no ecommerce data. Many thanks

Comment: sorry didn t tag you in the last comment please see bove thanks!

Comment: See if it is maybe the naming 'CARATracker'. Remove that and see if it arrives then.

Comment: I have tried removing it but it stil doesn t seem to be recording it the reason it was added was because there is another Google analytics script  on the page so I needed to differentiate between the two - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce see multiple tracker support

Comment: Using GA Debug in Chrome I see the following: Running command: ga("CARATracker.require", "ecommerce")
analytics_debug.js:9 Plugin "ecommerce" intialized on tracker "CARATracker".
analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("CARATracker.ecommerce:addTransaction", "1141701", "", "198.00", "", "0.00", "", "", "")
analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("CARATracker.ecommerce:addItem", {orderNo: "1141701", sku: "01327701", productName: "OKI C511dn", productCategory: "OKI Laser printers", price: "165.00", quantity: "1"})
analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("CARATracker.ecommerce:send")